# I need to set default username(i.e username by windows log in) value in userid label for some security reasons and how can i do that?

Tags: java, swing

I need to set my user-id(default) from the windows logged in for security reason and i don't have any idea,
Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;  
public class PasswordFieldExample {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    JFrame f=new JFrame("User-ID");    
     final JLabel label = new JLabel();            
     label.setBounds(20,150, 200,50);  

     JLabel l1=new JLabel("User-Id:");    
        l1.setBounds(20,20, 80,30);    
        JButton b = new JButton("Login");  
        b.setBounds(100,120, 80,30);    
        final JTextField text = new JTextField(12); text.setText(System.getProperty("user.name")); text.setBounds(100, 20, 100, 30);
               f.add(l1); f.add(label); f.add(b); f.add(text);  
                f.setSize(300,300);    
                f.setLayout(null);    
                f.setVisible(true);     
               /** b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
                // public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {       
                 //  String data = "Username " + text.getText();
                  // label.setText(data);          
               // }  
        });   */
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: @Berger THANKS FOR UR REPLY FIRST

Comment: @Berger actuallyi need a default value for my user-id and that userid should be my windows logged in(username)

Comment: @Berger did u get my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use java's `System.getProperty("user.name");` for a default account name

Comment: i have already used that property in my code,in this code i  ll get the cursor in my user-id label that means i am able to change the name and i dont want need this property(because it is insecure). i need to protect my user-id and noone can change it

Comment: do `text.setEditable(false);`

Comment: Thanks for Your answer XtremeBaumer,but i have already done this thing..

Comment: @Vasanth then i don't get your problem. you want a default value which nobody can change, but it should be different for each user, right?

Comment: u r absolutely right @XtremeBaumer, that is my need

Comment: text.setText(System.getProperty("user.name")); 
     text.setEnabled(false);

Comment: from my understanding this is all that you need to do or am i missing something? doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: everything is fine,i got my need